# Pragmatically sync office 365 exchange online and GMAIL

Tags: gmail, exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices, gmail-api

So I would want below functionality;

1. Connect to GMAIL for Business using service account (**Already DONE**)
2. Get emails from gmail (**Got some API**)
3. Connect to office 365 using oAuth access token (**Will be done, I think no issues in it**)
4. Copy the gmail message to office 365 message.

> How can I do it?

Here is the code done so far to download message from Google;

Console.WriteLine("Connect to Google API");
            Console.WriteLine("=====================");

```
        String serviceAccountEmail = "3512650851-4tpr9073rju4deqtfjp210j07q52hu2j@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"My Project-d3e5dda28438.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            User = "<UserEmail for which to download message>",
            Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify }
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));


        var gmailservice = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {

            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "MyNewProject",
        });

        try
        {
            ListMessagesResponse messages = gmailservice.Users.Messages.List("<User Email>").Execute();
            IList<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Thread> threads = gmailservice.Users.Threads.List("<User Email>").Execute().Threads;
            List<Message> responsemessages = new List<Message>();
            responsemessages.AddRange(messages.Messages);

            foreach(Message msg in responsemessages)
            {
                Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest gr = gmailservice.Users.Messages.Get("<User Email>", msg.Id);
                gr.Format = Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Full;
                Message m = gr.Execute();

                if (gr.Format == Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw)
                {
                    byte[] decodedByte = FromBase64ForUrlString(m.Raw);

                    string base64Encoded = Convert.ToString(decodedByte);
                    MailMessage msg2 = new MailMessage();

                    //msg2.LoadMessage(decodedByte);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Note: The code is very rough for now. Will make it more formal later..

So basically the question is, How can I upload the message row format to office 365 or is there any ***COPY*** api?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any C# library/API that handles email synchronization, but maybe [Google finds you something](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+library+email+synchronization).

If not you will have to 'roll your own'. We are doing exactly that with calendar synchronization (in Delphi). The steps to take are:

[*Note that I am answering for full synchronization as your question title says*]

1. Analyze the email formats for both systems in detail. Set up data/storage structures that can handle all formats *and their differences*. You may have to resort to using 'extended/user defined/custom' properties to store properties of system Y in system X, when not present there. You will surely have to use custom properties for storing typical synchronization data: date of last synchronization, date of last change, maybe mutual IDs*
2. Read emails from both systems over a certain 'synchronization period'.
3. Do your own comparison looking for differences (added, deleted, modified emails)
4. Your comparison may have to take configuration/settings into account like *Do we synchronize both ways?*, *When an email is modified on both sides, which one takes precedence?*. That's not really necessary, you can define sensible defaults for that. Many synchronisation systems do, they don't ask your for any configuration, but then the user sometimes has to figure out *Huh, why did it update this way?*).
5. Write modifications to the external systems.

No small task, I can tell you, so I doubt it fits your your requirement *pragmatically*  ;-) So first invest heavily in searching if someone has already done this.
(And note that asking for libraries is off-topic in SO)

<sub>* You will even have to store 'my own ID' as a custom property for each email. If you don't do that you can't distinguish emails that were copied in the external system.</sub>